# Encrypt password using jquery and salt then verify salted password hash in php

Tags: php, jquery, hash, sha512

I implemented a salted password hash on the server-side using PHP.
Now I want that on the login page password should travel not in plain text but sha512 salted cipher text. I can implement this by using jQuery.

But the problem is how I can verify the password received from the client with a salted password saved in db using PHP.

Comment: What are you using to encrypt the password in the database? If you're using PHP's `crypt` then you could use `password_verify`.

Comment: I'm using PHP's Hash method.
$pass_hash = hash("sha512", $password);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get back the password from the hash or to convert the hash into another hash created using different algorithm or with different salt.

So you will have to fetch the salt from DB and use that to hash the password and then transmit it to server. I won't recommend transmitting salt to frontend. Instead you can use asymmetric key algorithm like RSA to encrypt password and then decrypt it using your private key, but if you have SSL installed on your server then it is not required. Since SSL performs this for you on its own.

Comment: So, have no salt-related content in the frontend, right?

Comment: yup, its not required if you are on a https connection. HTTPS protocol is built to transport content safely over internet to your server.